# Displaying username after they have logged in (newbie)

Tags: php

Hello im completely new to php and my question is how can i echo out the username of the person who has logged in, on the page they get sent to after logging in successfully?

ive got the login system working and everything but not sure where to write the session stuff etc.

**This is my login2a.php**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'assign02');

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM members
        WHERE username = '$username';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: login.html');
}

$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );


//check to see if the password is wrong if wrong redirect user to login forma again and if correct redirect to 
if($hash == $userData['password']) 
{
    header('Location: signed_in.php?username = $username ');
    //header('Location: login.html');
}else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
    //header('Location: signed_in.php?username=$username');
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

**This is the page that i want their username to be displayed, this is just some parts of the website because its too big, what ive echoed is completely wrong i know but hope someone could help me with this problem. This page is the signed_in.php**

```
 <div class="layout-978">
            <img id="content_background" src="Images/Background.png" />


                <div class="main_content">
                    <div id="top_sellers_title"> 
                        <div class="col7">

                            <!--username displayed to show logged in-->
                            <?php
                                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

                                    echo "<div id=\"welcome_msg\"> $username </div>";
                                }
                            ?>
```

Comment: is it possible to show me how to do this, sorry i know a bit about sessions but not enough :P thanks for the reply though

Comment: echo "<div id=\"welcome_msg\"> $_SESSION['username'] </div>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this in your login page and don't forget to use session_start(); at the very beginning of your login page.

```
if($hash == $userData['password']) 
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: signed_in.php');
    //header('Location: login.html');
}
```

Then in signed_in.php page, to display the username just do the following

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo '<div id="welcome_msg">'.$_SESSION['username'].  '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the reply sorry if this is a stupid question but do you mean i should add the session_start(); at the veery beginning on the login.html page or the login2a.php page which i just posted?

Comment: ive done everything and the good thing is i dont have any error messages however ive changed the font size to about 200px and nothing shows up so im guessing something is wrong... when i go to the signed in page it doesnt bring up the username

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start()` on top of both login2a.php and signed_in.php.
In your login2a.php file where you've successfully authenticated a user, create a session variable named username and assign the username you've passed to the query to that session variable. Here's how

```
.
.
.

if($hash == $userData['password']) 
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    // Continue with your code
}
```

Hope my answer helps

Comment: ive done everything and the good thing is i dont have any error messages however ive changed the font size to about 200px and nothing shows up so im guessing something is wrong... when i go to the signed in page it doesnt bring up the username

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see what does it dump. It might have been an issue with session not initializing properly.

Comment: hey thanks for the speedy reply, sorry this maybe a stupid question but where do i add this var dump script in? do i replace the $_SESSION['username'] = $username;?

Comment: Place it above the code where you want to the welcome message to be displayed. Double check if you set `session_start()` on both pages. They should be added on the top of the page.

Comment: hmm for some odd reason it works now after i emptied the cache of the browser as it might of been storing some old information. Thank you so much for your help it much appreciated

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept this as an answer by clicking on the checkbox right next to my original answe. Happy coding!